# preg_replace, unable to insert '\' '

Tags: php

I would like to define something like:

```
preg_replace('é','\\\'{e}', 
    preg_replace('à','\\`{a}',
    preg_replace('è','\\`{e}',
    preg_replace('ì','\\`{i}', 
    preg_replace('ò','\\`{o}', 
    preg_replace('ù','\\`{u}',$text))))))
```

I am trying to substitute

```
è --> \'{e}
à --> \`{a} and so on
```

I always get

```
Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '�' found in /var/www/html/..../ on line 22
```

Comment: I guess you need to escape this {u}( and {a}, {e}, {i}, {o}) like this \{u\} because for regular expression {} have especial meaning.

Comment: Start with [the documentation on PCRE functions](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php).  These are Perl-compatible regular expressions, and require delimiters like `/pattern/` or `#pattern#`

Comment: Following up with @MichaelBerkowski you would try changing your pattern to `/é/`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to not use `preg_replace` here, no need for regular expressions as there's a better way:

```
$find = array('é', 'à', 'è', 'ì', 'ò', 'ù');
$repl = array("\\'{e}", "\\`{a}", "\\`{e}", "\\`{i}", "\\`{o}", "\\`{u}");
$text = str_replace($find, $repl, $text);
```

But as your question, you made wrong nested `preg_replace` in addition to not having defined a **delimiter**. You can achieve what you need with working by `preg_replace_callback` as I noticed you want ***single quote*** for some accented characters and ***acute*** for the other ones:

*Update #1: Using `preg_replace_callback`*

```
$text = preg_replace_callback(
    '@é|à|è|ì|ò|ù@',
    function ($match)
    {
        return ($match[0] == 'é') ? "\\'é" : "\\`$match[0]";
    },
    $text
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `/` in the pattern. 
Try this way:

```
preg_replace('/é/','\\\'{e}', 
preg_replace('/à/','\\`{a}', 
preg_replace('/è/','\\`{e}', 
preg_replace('/ì/','\\`{i}', 
preg_replace('/ò/','\\`{o}', 
preg_replace('/ù/','\\`{u}',$text))))))
```